# Combo Box with a button in the Items Template

Tags: wpf, combobox, datatemplate

I would like to add a button to the combobox ItemTemplate, that allows the user to click it and remove the clicked item.

This is what i have so far:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="cboUserCustomReports"
                      Width="300" Height="Auto"
                      Margin="0,5,0,5"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserReportProfileList,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      EditValue="{Binding Path=UserReportProfileID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ValueMember="UserReportProfileID"
                      DisplayMember="ReportName"
                      PopupClosed="cboUserCustomReports_PopupClosed">
            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="23"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding XPath=ReportName}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                                Width="23" Height="23"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="/RMSCommon;component/Resources/Delete.ico"></Image>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

My problem is that my Displaymember is not showing in the TextBlock and only the image of the button template is showing.

Here is a picture of what it looks like:

[image: ComboBox]

How do i solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Or is there a more logical way to approach this problem?

Comment: IMO this is a nice way. You also can change the items-container, but your solution looks to me absolutely appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DisplayMember will not work if you have defined a DataTemplate. However I have seen that you have a TextBlock with a XPath-binding to *ReportName*. This should do the trick. Check this binding, I assume that there in is the mistake. Check the Visual Studio output-window for binding errors.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
           Text="{Binding XPath=ReportName}"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment
```

Are you shure that you need an XPath-binding? If you're not sure, try to replace `Text="{Binding XPath=ReportName}"` through `Text="{Binding ReportName}"`. Maybe this is the only problem.

Comment: Now my question is, how do i get my button to be click-able?

Comment: You can register a general handler for Button.Click or you can register an event-handler directly on the DataTemplate. But I recommend to create a new post because it's a new question...